login security spring boot
public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
    authenticationManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                request.getEmail(),
                request.getPassword()
        )
    );
    var user = repository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(new HashMap<>(),user);
    return AuthenticationResponse.builder() 
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
}

it always return 403 error and permit the users from login how to fix that

debugging is a good idea in such cases. If you look into the constructor you are calling you will see the following code:
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(null);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        setAuthenticated(false);
    }

as you see, the constructor you are calling, sets authenticated as false.
You want to call a different constructor, with new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword(), List.of()) which will call the following overload
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(authorities);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
    }

Imo Spring Security made a bad decision here with these overloads which confuse many programmers, and should have went with static methods with descriptive names, but they for sure had their reasons.
